# perf report - what are the two percentage columns

Tags: perf

Does anyone know where the perf report outputs are documented?  Or in particular what the two percentage columns on the left are?  I have found a number of examples showing a single percentage column but I get two.  The commands I used are given below.

Many thanks!

```
 perf record -g -a sleep 1
 # Note: -a == all cpus -g enables backtrace recording for call graphs
 perf report
 +   78.09%     0.00%   node  libc-2.19.so  [.] __libc_start_main
 +   77.71%     0.00%   node  node          [.] node::Start(int, char**)
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Using `-a` does not make a  lot of sense if you want to inspect the `sleep` command.
2. It is usually percentage of time spend in the function. The first one together with all the children (calls from the function) and the second the function itself without children.

Comment: (2) That makes sense, however I am unsure why I get one column on a single-processor system and two on multiprocessor systems.  Do you have references for the column definitions? (1) Brendan Gregg writes:  `# CPU counter statistics for the entire system, for 5 seconds:`
`perf stat -a sleep 5`  so I was under the impression that this was profiling everything in the system.  The above report includes a lot of node, for example, which definitely isn't included in `sleep` so I think the command is right, no?  http://www.brendangregg.com/perf.html

Comment: `perf report --no-children` shows only one column, so I think you are right on that point!